# OnPostExecute method not parsing JSON array

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

The method is suppose to grab the required strings from the JSON array and set them to be the value of the individual textviews but the try block doesnt work..always stops at the catch block...

this is the class

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.nairation.library.JSONParser;
import com.nairation.library.NetworkUtil;
import com.nairation.library.UserFunctions;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class TopicView extends Activity{

    private TextView tname;
    private TextView uname;
    private TextView tcontent;
    private String val;
    private String val1;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private LinearLayout Progress, nilinter;
    private String gh;
    private UserFunctions userf;
    private JSONParser parser;
    public static final String CONTENT = "content";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.topic_view);
        tname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.topic_name);
        uname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.topic_username);
        tcontent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.topic_content);
        nilinter = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.noInterLayout);
        Progress = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.topicProg);
        val = getIntent().getExtras().getString("tname").toString();
        val1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("tid").toString();
        tname.setText(val);

        if(val.length() > 19){
            gh = val.substring(0, 20) + "...";
        }else{
            gh = val;
        }

        //Action bar settings....
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(gh);
        final int actionBarColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.nGreen);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(actionBarColor));
        int interStatus = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(getApplicationContext());

        if(interStatus != 0){
            new TopicSync().execute(Integer.parseInt(val1));
        }else{
            nilinter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private class TopicSync extends AsyncTask<Integer, JSONObject, JSONObject>{
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int topicId = params[0];
            userf = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject jp = userf.getTopicView(topicId);
            return jp;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
            try{
                JSONArray feed = result.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < feed.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject feeda = feed.getJSONObject(i);
                    String content = feeda.getString("user");
                    String username = feeda.getString("user");
                    uname.setText(username);
                    tcontent.setText(content);
                    publishProgress(feeda);
                }
                Progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Problem with loading topic", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        onBackPressed();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

and this is the JSON object that comes from the PHP file

```
'{"data":[{"content":"<p><img src=\"https:\/\/ucarecdn.com\/9993f861-212b-4ee1-b89e-af6f414948f8\/\" \/><\/p>\n","user":"mash"}]}'
```

so please what could be the problem

LOGCAT output

```
10-09 02:16:37.455: W/System.err(7420): org.json.JSONException: No value for user
10-09 02:16:37.465: W/System.err(7420):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
10-09 02:16:37.465: W/System.err(7420):     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:514)
10-09 02:16:37.465: W/System.err(7420):     at com.nairation.rss.TopicView$TopicSync.onPostExecute(TopicView.java:105)
10-09 02:16:37.465: W/System.err(7420):     at com.nairation.rss.TopicView$TopicSync.onPostExecute(TopicView.java:1)
10-09 02:16:37.465: W/System.err(7420):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
10-09 02:16:37.465: W/System.err(7420):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
10-09 02:16:37.465: W/System.err(7420):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
10-09 02:16:37.465: W/System.err(7420):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-09 02:16:37.465: W/System.err(7420):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-09 02:16:37.465: W/System.err(7420):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
10-09 02:16:37.465: W/System.err(7420):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 02:16:37.465: W/System.err(7420):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-09 02:16:37.465: W/System.err(7420):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
10-09 02:16:37.465: W/System.err(7420):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
10-09 02:16:37.465: W/System.err(7420):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 02:17:10.350: W/ViewRootImpl(7420): Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=158, metaState=0, flags=0x48, repeatCount=0, eventTime=350819868, downTime=350819868, deviceId=10, source=0x101 }
```

Comment: look and see what the error is...

Comment: Where is the problem exactly? Did you debug it and check the value of the variable JSONArray feed?

Comment: Could you post the stack trace from your logCat?

Comment: @Trein i tried doing dat but i couldnt display the value of the json array cos i can't get any string from the JSON

Comment: @tyczj please i ve bin looking at this class since yesterday til now i can't seem to get where the error is from

Comment: Your JSON parsing seems correct unless you are not getting this json, check in doinbkg function if you can parse the json, remoeve the UI related code while checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the reference about JSONObject [getString](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29), if there is no string value for the key, it will throw the exception. That means no "user" existed.

```
 String content = feeda.getString("user");
 String username = feeda.getString("user");
```

So you'd better debug to `JSONObject feeda = feed.getJSONObject(i);` to check the value of feeda or log it out to check what's inside. Probably your PHP file not read correctly.

Comment: my problem was i mistakenly forgot to type an 'e' in front of 'true' in my php file..feel like killing myself..